# filter not working in mongoose when i trying to filter a tag . instead it shows all the posts without filter

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

my problem is i fetch a url in front end part(react) of website to fetch all posts

and it works fine

but when i try to filter posts by their tags and show just posts with that tag

instead it shows all posts

i can not understand why this happening . maybe problem with my fetch ?

this is the code of front end part

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchAgain = async () => {
      if (posts != null) {
        let skip = posts.length;
        // await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/posts?limit=6&skip=${skip}`)
        await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/posts?limit=6&skip=${skip}`)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((result) => setposts([...posts, ...result]));
      }
    };

    const handleScroll = () => {
      const html = document.documentElement;
      const body = document.body;
      const windowheight =
        "innerHeight" in window ? window.innerHeight : html.offsetHeight;

      const docHeight = Math.max(
        body.scrollHeight,
        body.offsetHeight,
        html.clientHeight,
        html.scrollHeight,
        html.offsetHeight
      );

      const windowBottom = windowheight + window.pageYOffset;
      if (windowBottom >= docHeight) {
        console.log("we reached the bottom");
        fetchAgain();
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

    return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  }, [posts]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
      // const res = await fetch(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/posts`)
      const res = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/posts");
      
      const data = await res.json();

      setposts(data);
      console.log(data);
    }, 2000);
  }, []);
```

and this is the backend part

```
const getPosts = async (req, res) => {
  const { userId } = req.params;
  const limitValue = req.query.limit || 6;
  const skipValue = req.query.skip  ||  0;
 
 

  const posts = await Post.find(userId ? { bookmarks: userId } : {})
    .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
    .populate("author")
    .populate("tags")
    .skip(skipValue) 
     .limit(limitValue)


  if (!posts) res.status(204).json("No posts found");
  else {
    res.status(200).json(posts.map((post) => post.toObject({ getters: true })));
  }
};
```

i can not understand why fetch all the posts instead of posts with their tags

please some one help me please

Comment: `userId` is `undefined`. You never send it

Comment: can u explain a little more ? do u know what i am thinking there was a component like this <post filteredtag={filteredtag}>   i think this problem occured when i add infinity scroll to the site . but i can not fix it any more